# K-fold cross validation for kNN Imputer in Python

Tags: python, cross-validation, data-imputation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a dataset with columns, say, `y, x1, x2, x2` and a lot of missing values in `x1, x2, x3`. I decided to use `KNNImputer` from `sklearn.impute` to fill these NaNs. Later on, I would like to fit a few models, like XGBoost, Artificial Neural Networks, Random Forests, etc. and measure my score via k-fold cross validation, as I don't have a test set. The thing is that I would like to also investigate how the number of neighbours in KNNImputer affects the results. What should I do? Let's say that's (a very small) part of my data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'y':['5', '2', '1', '9', '8'], 
                     'x1':["NaN", 0.8, 1.5, "NaN", 0.3],
                     'x2':[22.1, "NaN", 13.7, 18.2, 10],
                     'x3':[5, "NaN", "NaN", 3, 7]})
# Imputing 

imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = 5, weights = 'distance')
imputer.fit((data.loc[:,["x1", "x2", "x3"]]))
data.loc[:,["x1", "x2", "x3"]] = imputer.transform(data.loc[:,["x1", "x2", "x3"]])

# XGBoosting

import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import cv
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

params = {
            'max_depth': 4,
            'alpha': 10,
            'learning_rate': 1.0,
            'n_estimators':100
        }         
           
          
# instantiate the classifier 
xgb_clf = XGBClassifier(**params)


# fit the classifier to the training data
xgb_clf.fit(datax[["x1", "x2", "x3"]], datax["y"])
```

And there is of course `cv` function from `xgboost` but it doesn't help with k-fold CV for KNN imputer. I guess I would need to do a pipeline, am I right? Could you help me put it all together?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The way to go is to setup a pipeline and run `GridSearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV` over it.